# How to export bookmarks from default android browser?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, bookmarks

I am using LG P500 phone, running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).

I want to export bookmarks from default browser of my android phone.

Can any one suggest me how to do that?

I have checked settings of default browser but no clue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are apps that can backup your bookmarks, e.g.

[GMarks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thomnichols.android.gmarks) or [TitaniumBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (needs root).

You could also sync the P500 bookmarks with Google (by default on) and also set up sync for a regular desktop chrome browser (very prominently accessible in the settings).

You should be able to export your bookmarks then.